# "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" when using sudo in a remote script

Tags: bash, ssh, sudo

I want to run a series of sudo-elevated commands on a remote machine from an embedded script. To simplify the question, I'm just trying to run sudo id and get it to tell me that it's root.

I am encountering "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" when I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t 192.168.1.100<<EOF
sudo id
EOF
```

But not when I run this:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t 192.168.1.100 sudo id
```

How do I get the first one, with the end-of-file designations for an embedded script to respect the forced tty at the other end of the SSH?

Comment: I can't change the /etc/sudoers to remove the requiretty and I'm required to use a password to elevate with sudo.

Comment: also, I am already using the -t option on my ssh, it just that the embedded script within the EOF tags isn't respecting the forced tty

Answer (score 2):

With the first one there is no `tty` for `ssh` since `stdin` is not connected to the terminal, it is a here file. In fact if I try to run a similar command (on Debian) I get the following error:

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

To get it to work you can do something like:

```
ssh -tt 192.168.1.100 <<EOF
sudo -S id
password
EOF
```

Although this is not a good idea since the password will be in plain text.

#### Update

I stumbled across an easy solution to this that avoids encoding the password in plain text, you can use a graphical program to enter the password:

```
ssh -X 192.168.1.100 <<EOF
SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass sudo -A id
EOF
```

Of course the `ssh-askpass` program must be installed in the given location and you must be running an X session on the machine you are working on. There are a few variations on the `ssh-askpass` program which should also work (Gnome/KDE versions). Also a graphical `sudo` replacement program like `gksu` or `kdesudo` should do the job too.

Comment: That doesn't work for me either. I get tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: @Andy, yes, it will since there is no actual terminal but `sudo` still tries to read the password form it. It is possible to use `-S` to make it read the password from `stdin` (not recommended though), see my edit.

Comment: It also outputs the password in clear text and still doesn't run the command.

Comment: @Andy, I had the same effect, yes. It did run the command though.

Comment: The answer suggested at http://serverfault.com/questions/479553/run-multiple-commands-over-ssh-as-sudo works for a simple command (like sudo id), but for my more complex scripts, it doesn't interpret correctly.

Comment: Displaying the password in clear text either in the script or in the stdout doesn't work for me. I'm fine with it prompting me for my password again to elevate my priveleges "[sudo] password for user:"

Comment: @Andy, for this I was just trying to show why the here file approach wasn't working and why it isn't really a good idea anyway. I can't suggest a better solution without knowing more about what you are trying to do. Although you can also have something like `ssh -t host 'sudo id; echo "non-root command"; sudo echo "another root command"'` in addition to using `bash -c`. The trick is usually just to make sure things are correctly quoted.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the suggestion. My script was already written to use ssh root@host, but they took root access away and forced me to use sudo. so I'm trying to substitute in the sudo commands for a variety of system checks. simple things, like looking for certain users in the /etc/sudoers file. Most of the script runs fine as myself, but for those few places I need to escalate, I have to use sudo.

Comment: @Andy, updated with a possible way to work around this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's not going to work for me as I can't install things on the remote system, but it's an interesting solution to the problem.